# What is this plant with serrated leaves and small white/yellow flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

Can you help me identify this plant?

[image]

It opens in the morning and closes in the afternoon.

It is growing in my backyard in Buenos Aires, Argentina.

It started growing a few months ago, it does not have scent and this is the first flower it has.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi F.C. Can you answer a few questions about this pretty plant? Is it a vine? Does the flower have a scent? Is it wild, or did you plant it there? Has it ever produced fruit? (I ask that because from a quick online search it looks a little bit like a wild strawberry, though not an exact match.) Is it a perennial? What months does it generally flower? What are your average temperatures? Are there any other details you can think of that might be helpful? You can just add these things right into your question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's Sida rhombifolia - Arrowleaf Sida. The leaf form seems to vary from narrow to broad, based on the pictures I scrolled through, and only occasionally displays those prominent horn like features at the sides.

Comment: Also known as 'Cuban sida'. Used in herbal medicine - a tea made from the upper part of the plants is reputed to combat gout and similar ailments.